# Error in applying UPGRADE lock in criteria in HIbernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am developing an application that uses oracle database.To connect with database I am using Hibernate.I am new to Hibernate and stuck with an issue so need some help.
My scenario is:

1. Select some rows from database whose processingStatus(a column in my table) is ‘N’
2. Update ProcessingStatus for those rows to ‘U’
3. Apply some logic on data
4. Change ProcessingStatus to ‘Y’

I wrote a code that will work fine if I run it as single process , but problem will come if I run multiple instances of same application , there different process might pick up same rows for processing which I don’t want.
So I want to lock all rows that are return by select rows update their ProcessingStatus to ‘U’ then release the lock.
For doing this I got an API in Criteria `criteria.setLockMode(LockMode.UPGRADE)` , I plan to use this while running select query so that any other row won’t select these rows but problem is when I am using this API I getting error
Error is:

```
2602 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: -11, SQLState: 37000
2602 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: -11, SQLState: 37000
2603 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Unexpected token: FOR in statement [select this_.CUSTOMER_ID as CUSTOMER1_2_0_, this_.MARKETPLACE_ID as MARKETPL2_2_0_, this_.PROCESSING_DATE as PROCESSING3_2_0_, this_.AMOUNT as AMOUNT2_0_, this_.LAST_SHIP_DATE as LAST5_2_0_, this_.ORDER_DATE as ORDER6_2_0_, this_.PROCESSING_STATUS as PROCESSING7_2_0_, this_.PURCHASE_ID as PURCHASE8_2_0_, this_.QUANTITY as QUANTITY2_0_ from CUSTOMERS_FIRST_ORDER this_ where this_.PROCESSING_DATE=? and this_.MARKETPLACE_ID=? and this_.PROCESSING_STATUS=? limit ? for update]
```

Can someone please help me with this.I am not getting what I am doing wrong.If I use `LockMode.READ` then it works but it thows error with UPGRADE/WRITE mode.

Piece of code which throws error is :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public List<CustomerFirstOrder> getOrders(final Date processingDate, long marketplaceID, int count) throws Exception {
    final Session session = getSession();
    final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CustomerFirstOrder.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(PROCESSING_DATE, processingDate));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(MARKETPLACE_ID, marketplaceID));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(PROCESSING_STATUS, ProcessingStatus.NOTPROCESSED.toString().charAt(0)));                ///Select only unprocessed rows
    criteria.setMaxResults(count); // select multiple rows
    criteria.setLockMode(LockMode.UPGRADE);
    LOGGER.debug("selecting multple row for date " + processingDate + " of marketplace " + marketplaceID + " of status " + ProcessingStatus.NOTPROCESSED);
    final List<CustomerFirstOrder> results;
    try {
            results = (List<CustomerFirstOrder>)criteria.list();
            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are known issues with using limits and the for update clause in Oracle, via Hibernate, dating back at least a couple years. See [this bug report](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-759). Try taking out the following line:

```
criteria.setMaxResults(count);
```

And running the test again. As a side note, `LockMode.UPGRADE` is deprecated in Hibernate, you should be using `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` instead.

Comment: I have 1 more question when this lock will be released?
Will it get release by itself when transaction is finished or I have to manually unlock it

Comment: You appear to be using declarative transactions, which mean Hibernate is automatically managing your transactions for you and in this case it appears your transaction will end when the method returns. Not what you want if I understand what you are doing. Normally, you manage your own transactions if you are using pessimistic locks on the DB. Also, you should try and process those records ***quickly*** and commit the results - holding DB locks for an extended period of time will retard the performance of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't support `limit` clause thus Hibernate cannot generate a query with `limit` clause if it's configured to use Oracle dialect.

So, you need to [configure Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects) to use the correct Oracle dialect to make Hibernate generate correct queries for Oracle.

Comment: I have 1 more question when this lock will be released?
Will it get release by itself when transaction is finished or I have to manually unlock it

Comment: @Rahul: `LockMode.UPGRADE` turns into `select ... for update` lock that's released at the end of transaction.